# My while function is not returning any value ! What am i doing wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Quite newbie to this !

i have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
currentMilestone            m2          SLA_M6          latedeliverydate            SLA_M3          earlypickupdate
            m2      2020-02-21      2020-02-18              2020-03-14          2020-02-09              2020-02-08
            m2      2020-02-21      2020-02-18              2020-02-14          2020-02-09              2020-02-08
            m2      2020-02-21      2020-02-18              2020-02-14          2020-02-09              2020-02-08
            m2      2020-02-21      2020-02-18              2020-02-14          2020-02-09              2020-02-08
            m1             NaT      2020-03-24              2020-02-14          2020-03-13              2020-03-18
```

i have written that looks like this:

```
def flag(data):

    while data.currentMilestone== 'm1'is True:

        if data.SLA_M6  > data.latedeliverydate:
            return 'R'
        elif (data.SLA_M3 != data.earlypickupdate) & (data.latedeliverydate <= data.SLA_M6):
            return 'A'

        elif (data.SLA_M3 == data.earlypickupdate) & (data.latedeliverydate >= data.earlypickupdate):
            return 'G'
        else:
            return None
```

the expected output is :

```
currentMilestone            m2          SLA_M6          latedeliverydate            SLA_M3          earlypickupdate         flag
            m2      2020-02-21      2020-02-18              2020-03-14          2020-02-09              2020-02-08          None    
            m2      2020-02-21      2020-02-18              2020-02-14          2020-02-09              2020-02-08          None
            m2      2020-02-21      2020-02-18              2020-02-14          2020-02-09              2020-02-08          None
            m2      2020-02-21      2020-02-18              2020-02-14          2020-02-09              2020-02-08          None
            m1             NaT      2020-03-24              2020-02-14          2020-03-13              2020-03-18            R
```

When i run my function i dont have any result ... I mean the flag is not working properly. All rows are set to None

What wrong here ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `while`, since you always `return` in every condition.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Returning a value doesn't add a column to a dataframe.

Comment: General tip: there's no need for `is True` after a conditional expression.

Comment: data['flag']=data.apply(flag,axis=1)

Comment: Edit the question to add a [mcve] with the code.

Comment: if `data.currentMilestone== 'm1'` isn't true when you first call the funciton, then the while never runs, you don't explicitly return a value so python returns a None.

Comment: for the cases when it's true it should run, i'd expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for this since `apply` is very inefficient:

```
import numpy as np

cond1 = data['currentMilestone'] == 'm1'

condlist = [
    (data['SLA_M6'] > data['latedeliverydate']) & cond1,
    (data['SLA_M3'] != data['earlypickupdate']) & (data['latedeliverydate'] <= data['SLA_M6']) & cond1,
    (data['SLA_M3'] == data['earlypickupdate']) & (data['latedeliverydate'] >= data['earlypickupdate']) & cond1
]

choicelist = ['R', 'A', 'G']

data['flag'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=None)
```

[out]

```
  currentMilestone         m2     SLA_M6 latedeliverydate     SLA_M3 earlypickupdate  flag
0               m2 2020-02-21 2020-02-18       2020-03-14 2020-02-09      2020-02-08  None
1               m2 2020-02-21 2020-02-18       2020-02-14 2020-02-09      2020-02-08  None
2               m2 2020-02-21 2020-02-18       2020-02-14 2020-02-09      2020-02-08  None
3               m2 2020-02-21 2020-02-18       2020-02-14 2020-02-09      2020-02-08  None
4               m1        NaT 2020-03-24       2020-02-14 2020-03-13      2020-03-18     R
```

Comment: You may want to double check your logic and expected output however, because none of these conditions are evaluating as `True`

Comment: Sure, i have updated the data so that the last row would be evaluated as 'True'